# Won't compile after installing: Mcv.Mailer version 1.0 uses Mvc version 4.0, which has higher version than referenced assembly Mvc version 3.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-config, asp.net-mvc-4

I installed the nuget package for MvcMailer, found [here](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide). Although it didn't (as it says in the tutorial it will) add smtp configuration to web.config, I found the correct smtp configuration [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek2MvcMailerSendsMailsWithASPNETMVCRazorViewsAndScaffolding.aspx).

I'm using MVC4 in VS2010.

When I compile, I get the following error in the the error list:

> Error 1   Assembly 'Mvc.Mailer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'   c:\Users\Home\Desktop\MVCMusicStore - Copy\packages\MvcMailer.4.0\lib\40\Mvc.Mailer.dll MVCMusicStore

I also get the following warning:

> Warning   2   Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly.  MVCMusicStore

I removed the MvcMailer reference and added it again, but it didn't resolve the issue.

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using Mvc 4, and was installing MvcMailer via the package manager with the following:

```
install-package MvcMailer
```

Because I'm using Mvc 4, the following should be used:

```
install-package MvcMailer3
```

This has resolved the issue.