# Cannot use MvcMailer NuGet install on .Net Framework 4 (4.0.3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, nuget, mvcmailer

I followed the [step by step guide](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide) to install MvcMailer via NuGet but:

1. that didn't install any new Reference to my project
2. the `using Mvc.Mailer` is not resolved on the UserMailer.cs

this version is supposed to be compatible with .Net 4.0... Am I missing something ? Do I have something to install manually ?

If anybody has an alternative solution to this, I am just looking for a "clean" way to generate email within my MVC4 project .Net Framework 4 (4.0.3)

Thanks

Comment: oups I just read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13323977/wont-compile-after-installing-mcv-mailer-version-1-0-uses-mvc-version-4-0-whi

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, It was resolved with `4.0.0 version of mvc Mailer`

```
PM> Install-Package MvcMailer -Version 4.0.0`
```